# Why does Bootstrap add so much input lag when there's many inputs in Chrome?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I've been struggling to understand why Bootstrap adds so much overhead for character input when there's many text inputs on a page.

Here's a couple jsfiddles I created while I was trying to repro, debug, and troubleshoot this issue:

Simple React app **with Bootstrap** that creates 1500 inputs (~415ms/char):
https://jsfiddle.net/nwt6ou9L/20/

Simple React app **without Bootstrap** that creates 1500 inputs (~30ms/char):
https://jsfiddle.net/nwt6ou9L/21/

Simple React app **with Bootstrap** that creates only 300 inputs (~30ms/char):
https://jsfiddle.net/nwt6ou9L/44/

Simple React app **with Bootstrap** loaded but not using any Bootstrap tags (~415ms/char): 
https://jsfiddle.net/nwt6ou9L/24/

No React **only Bootstrap**  1500 inputs (~415ms/char): 
https://jsfiddle.net/nwt6ou9L/49/

Something that I found quite interesting is if you change the styling of the input field to something such as:

```
.text-input-column {
    position: relative !important
}
```

or

```
.text-input-column {
    all: unset;
}
```

The input lag disappears.

Given how long Bootstrap takes to render 1500 inputs, I would expect that rendering 300 would be close to 1/5th the time (About 83ms). But from my experience rendering 300 inputs is more within the range of ~20-22ms. So there's definitely some non-linear scaling going on.

Also, if you use Chrove Dev tools to do some profiling, you'll see that the 'Update Layer Tree' takes up most of the time for displaying a frame. How is it that adding a single character to an input field can cause so much work in the Layer Tree? What is Bootstrap doing to cause such a long update? **On Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

[image: Image of a single frame of link #1]
[image: Image of a single frame of link #2]

---

(ms/char) refers to the milliseconds it takes to render the input after the onChange event of entering a single character on my machine.

**And to be extremely clear, I'm not asking about whether or not having a ton of inputs on a page is the good UX, I'm asking about where this input lag comes from**

EDIT: I've continued to look into this issue and it appears it might be a Chrome only issue. **Firefox (version: 58.0.2 (64-bit))** does not seem to have this input lag overhead. It can render a character into the input field in ~40ms:

[image: 1500 Inputs on Firefox]

Comment: Why is my question getting downvoted without comment? I provided as much information as I can about the issue...

Comment: No idea because the question seems fine to me. I am interested to see what the answer is

Comment: Hopefully someone with more in-depth knowledge of Chrome's internals will come around.

I feel like at worst, it's a defect in Chrome's rendering engine. However, I have the suspicion that the problem still exists in Firefox but the effects are minimized because of Firefox Quantum's new rendering system.

I've noticed that if I render the inputs in Firefox and add a button that does something like open a modal, the time from clicking the "open modal button" to displaying the modal is just as bad.

Comment: This is way beyond my skill level but you might want to check out this [list](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/browser-bugs/) to see if the issue is on there anywhere. If it isn't then perhaps its not a browser specific issue?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. What a pain. Didn't know CSS could have such a huge effect on the page speed

Comment: Works good for me in Chrome 89. The lag is either related to browser version and/or bootstrap alpha version.  Building react files might see some difference

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Bootstrap 4 alpha, not anywhere close to the latest stable version 4.2.1...

On a lark, I tried replacing it with the latest version, and the issue is either entirely gone or greatly reduced.